# C++ asterisk asterisk operator

Tags: c++, operators, sfml

I have never seen this operation done before in any languages, since this is a symbol google makes it hard to search.

What does ** mean ?

```
sf::TcpSocket& client = **it;
```

Comment: is "it" a pointer or iterator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's [dereferencing](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) a pointer to a pointer, in order to get to the original `sf:TcpSocket`.

It's just two `*` operators in a row.

In this case, you could also write:

```
// Given sf::TcpSocket **it;
sf::TcpSocket *tmp = *it; // Dereference once
sf::TcpSocket& client = *tmp;
```

Comment: i read that page already :P i still don't really get it :/. Could you give a better example of this :)

Comment: Given the name of the variable being dereferenced, it's most probably dereferencing an iterator to a pointer.  It's not just pointers that can be dereferenced.

Comment: @Kyosu if you have an object, an int, say:  `int i = 0`, and a pointer to an int: `int* j`, you can assign the address of your int (i) like this: `j = &i`. If you wanted to then access the value of the int through `j`, you would have to dereference the pointer (ie access the object it's pointing to) like this `int k = *j`. If you created a new pointer to a pointer to an int: `int** l = &j`, to access the original int through this new pointer you would have to dereference twice: `int m = **l`. Or you could modify the value of i through the second pointer like this: `**l = 10`.

Comment: YEAH DAWG! :) Thanks Reed Copsey and James :) you helped me very very much :)

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to iterators as well :D

Answer (score 0):

I will give a very simple quick illustration:

```
int **i;
Say i stores an address 0x1234
*i gives us the value say 0x5678 stored on address 0x1234.
**i gives us the desired value stored on address 0x5678.
```

You can continue to do that until its a valid address space.
But by declaring.

```
          int **i;
```

We strictly have to deference only twice, any further attempt will be thwarted by the compiler. Thus avoid bugs. :-)